How is this SS assembly manufactured?
I really thought I could DIY this stainless steel piece but now I'm confused.
How did they mount the thin SS304 pipe into the gap on the SS304 sheet?


Thank you.

are you asking what keeps it from falling out of the hole?

Looks like a laser weld on the bottom side.

Probably a friction weld or a press fit. the press fit can be disassembled by chilling the tube and heating the sheet. a friction weld cannot.
